# Causal and probabilistic independence

Tags: probability

The concept of probabilistic independence is often confused with the concept of causal independence. We can often read:

“Two events are independent if the occurrence of one event does not influence (and is not influenced by) the occurrence of the other.”

And after that introduction of the notion of causal independence, the discussion continues with the tacit transition to the concept of probabilistic independence (P(A&B) = P(A)P(B)). For example, when a verification of the causal independence of two events is required, it is often carried out by a verification of probabilistic independence.

But the concept of causal independence is not equivalent to the concept of probabilistic independence. The second follows from the first, but the first does not follow from the second. Here is a simple proof that probabilistic independence does not imply causal independence:

You win if both coins fall on the same side. Since the probability of a head and a tail is ½, the probability of your victory is also ½ (because you win in 2 out of 4 possible cases). Your victory is obviously causally dependent on how the coins fall, but it is easy to prove that your victory is probabilistic independent of how the 1st coin falls and how the 2nd coin falls:

P(W & 1.H) = P(1.H & 2.T) = ½ ½ = P(W)P(1.H)

P(W & 1.T) = P(1.T & 2.H) = ½ ½ = P(W)P(1.T)

P(W & 2.H) = P(2.H & 1.T) = ½ ½ = P(W)P(2.H)

P(W & 2.T) = P(2.T & 1.H) = ½ ½ = P(W)P(2.T)

My experience is that this difference is not sufficiently known in probability circles (although it is well known in causality circles). Is my experience accurate or uninformed?

Comment: Reword the first as $\Pr(A\mid B) =\Pr(A)$.  You will find that in your example this is true as well.  "*Your victory is obviously causally dependent on how the* **COINS** *fall*"... yes, it is causally dependent on the combined result of *both* coins when considered together... however the point is that it is not causally dependent on the information on what the first *and only the first* coin is.

Comment: Further, you may be reaching for the fact that letting $A$ be the event the first coin is heads, $B$ the event the second coin is heads and $W$ the event that both coins match... you do have $A$ is independent of $B$, $A$ is independent of $W$, and $B$ is independent of $W$... the three are *pairwise* independent.  Yet, despite all of this you have that $A,B,W$ are not *mutually* independent, i.e. *collectively* independent.  This is a stronger condition and perfectly covered by a mathematical approach to defining things.

Comment: Do you think that causal and probabilistic independence are equivalent?

Comment: Yes and I think the difficulty you are experiencing stems from people misunderstanding definitions, misrepresenting definitions, having flawed intuition, or some combination of these.

Comment: The difficulty I am experiencing stems from understanding the concept of probabilistic causation (with a contribution to the field) and Pearl's resolution of some of its problems (cf. https://escholarship.org/uc/item/18j2x5zr). Pearl showed in many articles and books that causality does not reduce to probability (as hoped by Suppes and many others).

Comment: And what about spurious relationship (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spurious_relationship)?